# undefined method `boo' for Static:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, static-methods

I have a class in the lib directory:

`lib/static.rb`

Inside that I have:

```
class Static
  def self.boo
    return 'what'
  end
end
```

I have a controller:

```
class PensionsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'page'
  def guides
    render :text => Static.boo
  end
end
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `boo' for Static:Class
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Rails 2 or 3? In Rails 3 classes in the lib directory aren't loaded by default.

I have this line at the bottom of config/application.rb to enable that behavior:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: Rails 3, I tried detecting if the class exists and it returned true. Though, that did fix the problem.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried similar code and it worked for me. Maybe there's some conflicting class named Static? That's all I can think of right now

Comment: Is there a `require 'static'` at the top of the Controller?